# Cannot set value on checkbox using sObject via Partner API using Java

Tags: soap-api, integration, sobject, java, inputcheckboxes

I get an error when I try to set a checkbox with the Salesforce Partner API.

I have tried different combinations, but I get the error that an Object is required.

Confirmed__c is a checkbox and this is what I have tried

```
com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject record = new com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject();
record.setField("Confirmed__c",true);
record.setField("Confirmed__c",1);
record.setField("Confirmed__c","true");
record.setField("Confirmed__c","1");
```

This is the error I get when I compile

```
Incompatible type for method. Can't convert boolean to java.lang.Object.
record.setField("Confirmed__c",true);
```

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me out with the correct way to accomplish this. I tried to find some examples on the web and I found one post, where it appears the first option above have worked, so not sure why I am getting this error?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508026/how-to-disable-deactivate-a-salesforce-user-through-soap-api

Many Thanks,  Kent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Java is a bit rusty, but I think a `boolean` such as `true` is a primitive type.

Based on the error message:

> Incompatible type for method. Can't convert boolean to java.lang.Object.

it appears the `setField()` method wants an instance of java.lang.Object.

So what you really want for the second parameter is an instance of `Boolean` (note the upper case B), which is a reference type.

In this case Java isn't doing the "boxing conversion" from `boolean` to `Boolean` for you implicitly.

Try:

```
record.setField("Confirmed__c", new Boolean(true));
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that worked like a charm. Much appreciated!